# I do not understand what is happening with useEffect here

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load a user if the `token` in `localStorage` is found. Of course, nowhere in my code am I assigning `true` to `isAuthenticated` but my question more so is if I do the following...

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    const loadUser = async () => {
      await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'x-auth-token': localStorage.token,
        },
      });

      if (!mounted) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };

    loadUser();

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

I do not get this issue...
**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

However, if I were to change the

```
if (!mounted) {
  setIsAuthenticated(false);
}
```

to

```
if (!mounted) {
  setIsAuthenticated(true);
}
```

I do get that warning and I'm just wondering why this happens so that I know how to deal with it properly whenever it comes up.

Comment: You might want to refer: 
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component

Answer (score 1):

The warning is:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state **update** on an unmounted component.

You can call the state setter but you can't change the state because that will cause a re render but React can't re render because the component has been unmounted, see code below:

```
const Working = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //not changing the value
    setTimeout(() => setValue(true), 100);
  });
  return `value is: ${value}`;
};
const Warning = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //changing the value causes re render
    //  but component was unmounted by App
    setTimeout(() => setValue(false), 100);
  });
  return `value is: ${value}`;
};
const App = () => {
  const [remount, setRemount] = React.useState(true);
  const causeWarning = () => {
    setRemount(false);
    Promise.resolve(true)
      .then(setRemount)
      .then(() => setRemount(false));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={causeWarning}>cause warnig</button>
      {remount && <Working />}
      {remount && <Warning />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

It's best to not call the state setter at all when the component was unmounted:

```
if (mounted) {
  setIsAuthenticated(false);
}
```

The part where the warning says:

> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

Means that you may

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    const loadUser = async () => {
      await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'x-auth-token': localStorage.token,
        },
      }).then(()=> {
          if (!mounted) {
              setIsAuthenticated(true);
               }
            });
       };

    loadUser();

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: No, OP tries to call state setter deliberately on unmounted component: `if (!mounted) {`. It won't cause an error just to call the state setter but will when you **change** the state. The error is: "Warning: Can't perform a React state **update** on an unmounted component."